# Django queryset. Save all rows to a variable and delete rows in table

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I use mysql table as temporary storage of my data that I parse. I've tried to get data from the table, save it to variables, delete rows from table and bring model's objects (that were saved to the variables) to template, but unsuccessful. QuerySet are lazy, but I want to get data from table, not only pointers. How I could do this?

```
fop_rating = Edata.objects.values('recipt_name').filter(recipt_edrpou='xxxxxxxxxx').annotate(total=Sum('amount')).order_by('-total')[:10]

uric_rating = Edata.objects.values('recipt_name').exclude(recipt_edrpou='xxxxxxxxxx').annotate(total=Sum('amount')).order_by('-total')[:10]

rows = Edata.objects.filter(rand_ind=rand_ind)  
for r in rows: # delete all the rows
    r.delete()

return render(request,'edata/index.html',{"data":data,'fop_rating':fop_rating,'uric_rating':uric_rating})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs a slight change.

```
resp  = render(request,'edata/index.html',
  {"data":data,'fop_rating':fop_rating,'uric_rating':uric_rating})

Edata.objects.filter(rand_ind=rand_ind).delete()

return resp
```

note that you need to render the response before rows are deleted. Secondly you don't need to delete it row by row (that would be rather inefficient). You can bulk delete as above.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.